# Woocommerce Free shipping per category

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

Hey i have a coding question/request if possible:

Lets say:

One product category 299 shipping
3500 min. amount before free shipping

Second product category 99 shipping
1000 min. amount before free shipping

Third product category 49 shipping
600 min. amount before free shipping

and so on.

Mixing all of above product categories and 1 of them overrides or forces all shipping instances?

I searched and searched and couldnt really find anything on the above requested there is some out there but its not really it. I hoped there was a php script or plugin that could solve this issue.

Comment: This is easily doable using [woocommerce_package_rates hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=woocommerce_package_rates%20category&searchOn=3)

Comment: Im not really the best php coder, that is why i was looking for a solution if it is possible. Or if your able to do it, i would love to have a chat